# Getting rid of extensions in variables (CMD)

Tags: windows, get, cmd

CMD Q: I want to remove the extension of a filename.

It is actually a complete path, like C:/Me/My/Path/filename.xxxx

i know that the extension has 4 chars, like shown in example above.

How can i get rid of the extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In terminal:

```
set file=C:/Me/My/Path/filename.1234
for /F "tokens=*" %A IN ("%file%") DO @echo variable ^%file^%: %~dpnA
```

In batch file:

```
@echo off
set file=C:/Me/My/Path/filename.1234
echo If called with path as batch parameter: %~dpn1
for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%file%") DO echo variable %%file%%: %%~dpnA
```

Comment: have two questions: does this also delete the dot (.)? and: how do i delete with three (123)?

Comment: and: will this just change my variable, or do i have to add something to make it a variable?

Comment: Do you see 4 hardcoded anywhere? it removes the last . and everything after it. It does not change the variable, to change it, replace the echo with a set

Comment: so like `set filenew=%%~dpnA`?

Comment: and: is this good: `for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%file%") DO set filenr=%%A.aiff`

Comment: because it seems not. when i try to `echo %filenr`, it just gives `echo is off`, so it did not created the variable, or it is empty. What i did above was changing the extension in the variable to .aiff.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
@echo off
set fullpath= C:/Me/My/Path/filename.xxxx
set withoutext=%fullpath:~0,-5%
echo %withoutext%
```

The result is:

```
c:\>test
C:/Me/My/Path/filename
```

In this example script the last 5 characters are removed from the variable %fullpath%.

The syntax is explained here: http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=78901.0

In cases where the length of the extension is unknown this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
ren C:/Me/My/Path/filename.xxxx filename.
```

this should do it (the "." at the end is important)